# Visual Studio & Resharper: Rename class only in current project and not entire solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper

I have a solution with many projects in it.

Two projects both have a class with the same name. Lets call them **project A** and **project B**.

When i use resharper rename feature (Ctrl+R -> R) in **project B** and rename the class, then that new class name will be applied to **project A** as well.

**Before refactoring:**

Project A (ActorPool.h)

```
class ActorPool
{
  // ...
}
```

Project B (ActorPool.h)

```
class ActorPool
{
    //...
}
```

**After refactoring** (placing cursor on project B's ActorPool and ctrl+r -> r renaming ActorPool to ObjectPool)

Project A (ObjectPool.h)

```
class ObjectPool
{
  // ...
}
```

Project B (ObjectPool.h)

```
class ObjectPool
{
    //...
}
```

**Expected result after refactoring**:

Project A (ActorPool.h)

```
class ActorPool
{
  // ...
}
```

Project B (ObjectPool.h)

```
class ObjectPool
{
    //...
}
```

Here is the rename popup from resharper, i cant see any options to limit the scope of this refactor operation:

[image: Resharper Rename Popup]

How do i apply a rename through resharper only for the current project (e.g. the project the file belongs to, in my example project B, that contains the class that i'm performing the refactor on)?

Comment: If you're using C++, which I assumed you are based on `.h` extensions, then when you do `Ctrl+R+R` there's an option to "Skip preview changes", uncheck it. There's also an option to limit the scope to the current project.

Comment: @ChrisMM I have updated the answer with a screenshot of the popup im getting. I dont see any option like that unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you're using an extension which overrides what VS presents. I've not used that extension; seems a bit silly that the extension removes capabilities ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue [RSCPP-18643](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-18643) that does not have an ETA yet. Feel free to vote for/star this issue to subscribe for updates.

Comment: Thanks i have done that but its been open for 7 years, thats doesn't look very promising to be implemented any time soon even though its such an important feature. It basically makes renaming completely unusable feature once you have more than 1 project in VS